# Pagination not visible on woocommerce's category page

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, pagination

I am not able to display pagination on the category page on woocommerce, I have 18 products in a category but when I customise the rows and columns, it shows only a certain amount of products. I want to display only 6 pages per page. Please help.

Comment: Just FYI, some users consider woocommerce questions off topic.